# Laravel 5.4 JWT: 401 Unauthorized on Login with Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, jwt

I created a login API with JWT, I tested it with Postman and curl via terminal and it works great. But when I'm trying to get it to work using jQuery ajax and it responds with

> POST http://router.dev/api/login 401 (Unauthorized)

This is suppose to be on login, to generate a token. This is the ajax code:

```
var authenticate = function(){
        return $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            processData: false,
            contentType:  false,
            data: {email:'apitest@example.com',password:12346},
            url: 'http://router.dev/api/login'
        });
    }
```

And this is the auth method I'm using:

```
public function authenticate(Request $request){
    // grab credentials from the request
    $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');
    //dd($credentials);
    try {
        config(['auth.providers.users.model' => \App\Usuarios::class]);
        $token = JWTAuth::attempt($credentials);
        // dd($token);
        // attempt to verify the credentials and create a token for the user
        if (! $token) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'invalid_credentials'], 401);
        }
    } catch (JWTException $e) {
        // something went wrong whilst attempting to encode the token
        return response()->json(['error' => 'could_not_create_token'], 500);
    }
    // all good so return the token
    return response()->json(compact('token'));
}
```

Maybe it's something dull. Thanks in advance.

Comment: My guess would be you don't have a User with email 'apitest@example.com' and password '123456'. Possible?

Comment: You have a condition in your controller which returns a 401 when the login fails. So check your login credentials again. Also make sure you're not applying the jawtauth middleware to the login route, though considering it works in postman it shouldn't be the case.

Comment: When I use **data** it responds with unauthorized, but if I send the parameters directly via the **url** it works. `url: 'http://router.dev/api/login'http://router.dev/api/login?email=apitest@example.com&password=123456'`

Comment: @GabrielAlejandro Your password in the ajax request is `12346` and is sent as an integer. Where as your actual password from your comment is `123456`. That should fix it.